# Chaining ActiveRecord queries from different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models that belong_to the same model. I want to find all the matching parents in both models in one query if possible.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
locations = [1,2,3]
flight_results   = self.flights.where(from_id: locations).or(self.flights.where(to_id: locations))
waypoint_results = self.waypoints.where(location_id: locations)
search_results = flight_results + waypoint_results
search_results
```

The above returns an array, but because of a pagination gem that I'm using, I need to return an ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation.

Is this possible?

Comment: If the two models are different then there's no way you can do this. But you can paginate an Array, if you are using `Kaminari` https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object

Comment: As for `WillPaginate`, i don't know

Comment: I'm using `Kaminari` and am getting the exception `undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x007f8b100422f0>` Although, I suppose reading the `Kaminari` documentation would have been a great idea ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't merge 2 different Objects therefore you cna't merge 2 different collections of Objects.
You have to use an array (except if your flights and waypoints are in fact relations of the same model??)

BUT you can use an array in your pagination system.
Both Kaminari and will_paginate provide methods to do so.

Wich pagination gem do you use ?